# Using comments in script link tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What problems can be caused by placing comments in a script tag calling an external script? My coworker told me this is not a good practice.

Something like this:

```
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript">
            //    import jQuery
            //    cdn refers to a remotely hosted library
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your coworker is concerned you'll get in the habit of doing this

```
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript">
            //    import jQuery
            //    cdn refers to a remotely hosted library
</script>
```

And then eventually struggle to figure out why this doesn't work

```
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#ActionButton').click(DoAction);
     });
</script>
```

Because you've developed a bad habit

Answer (score 3):

Nothing wrong, maybe readability.
The content will also be overwritten by the source.

```
<!-- import jQuery. CDN refers to a remotely hosted library -->
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

No problems at all. If the `script` element has a `src` attribute, the content is ignored.

Maybe your coworker was referring to HTML comments inside the script tag, which where used for ancient browsers which did not support JavaScript?

```
<script>
   <!--
      // JS was here
   // -->
</script>
```

[Are HTML comments inside script tags a best practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808816/are-html-comments-inside-script-tags-a-best-practice)