# Difference in HTML/JavaScript parsing between WebView and browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview, android-browser

I'm hitting a very peculiar difference between the Android browser and a `WebView`. Namely, I have the following markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

    // some js code...

    // -->
</script>
```

Now, in the browser, this works perfectly fine. However, when loading the markup in the `WebView` using `loadData(markup, "text/html", "utf-8")`, the JavaScript code is not executed at all.

Now, if I remove the HTML comment tags (`<!--` and `-->`), it works fine in the `WebView` as well. However, this is not something that I want to do, because the markup is coming from a web service that I'd rather not change.

Is there something I can do with the `WebView` to accept this markup?

Comment: FWIW, http://stackoverflow.com/a/808850/115145

Comment: Beyond that, since you have the HTML as a `String`, you can parse out the comment yourself if you wanted.

Comment: @CommonsWare I know it's a very old habit, but it's just how this web service returns it. Also, it seems like a very common habit, so I find it weird that the `WebView` fails so badly with it, especially when the browser app handles it properly. And I'd rather stay away from string parsing, seems very hackish in this situation :).

Comment: I doubt that you're going to have much option other than the string parsing approach. You're welcome to file an issue on it -- I didn't see one when I searched -- and perhaps you'll get an official statement about it.

Comment: @CommonsWare [done](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58969). Feel free to add an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the whole, the [put-the-JavaScript-in-comments trick appears to be no longer the recommended pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/808850/115145), and so I'd encourage you to reconsider your plan to keep serving it that way.

You have obviously enabled JavaScript in the `WebView`, otherwise it would not work when you tried removing the comments. I know of no other setting to tell `WebView` to to ignore the comment markers.

You're welcome to examine [the AOSP Browser code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser) to try to find out what they do, though that code is nasty, brutish, and long. You could patch up the HTML before handing it to the `WebView`. You could set a particular user agent on the `WebView` and have your Web service hand back cleaned-up HTML for that user agent, leaving the rest of your Web service clients unaffected. And you can see if you get a response to [your bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58969), though there's no assurance of getting such a response.

Beyond that, I'm out of ideas.