# How can I autologin into a website with IE?

Tags: javascript, html, autologin

I use below source code in my script.

I worked fine with Crome Browser.

but didn't work with Internet Explorer.

How can I do?

somebody help me please.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        <!--
        function login() {
            document.form1.action="http://website.com/login/login.asp";
            document.form1.submit();
        }
        //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="login()">
<form method=post name="form1" id="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="ID_Text" value="abcd">
    <input type="hidden" name="PW_Text" value="abcd">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The attribute `language` is deprecated for the tag `script`, maybe IE is trying to validate your code (not sure about this...). You can try to change it to be `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: Can't test now, no IE at hand, but try in addition to @Totò's comment deleting `<!--` and `//-->`. It is [obsolete practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808816/are-html-comments-inside-script-tags-a-best-practice), it is actively harmful, and it's the only thing that I can see that might be a problem. Also, "didn't work" is rather vague. What happens? Any errors? Did the form submit but the login fail? What happens if you insert an `alert("before submit")` or three?

Comment: @Totò That is also pretty much useless. [sauce](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#the-script-element)

Comment: @PeeHaa true, it's the default value...

Comment: @Amadan Thanks for answer. Do the form submit, It has login fail.

Comment: @Totò Thanks for answer. I changed to <script type="text/javascript">
and delete comment code "<!-- //-->", but still failed login.

Comment: when I try login with IE. I saw error message "D:\path\path\.../include/left_mymenu.asp."

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<body onload="login">` (assigning function, not calling it)?

Answer (score 0):

I am pulling the answer out of your question for future visitors.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            BoardURL="http://WEBSITE.COM";
            UserName="abcd";
            PassWord="abcd";
            document.write('<form name="autoLogin" action="'+BoardURL+'/login/login.asp" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="ID_TEXT" value="'+UserName+'"><input type="hidden" name="PW_TEXT" value="'+PassWord+'">');
            document.forms[0].submit();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```