# Why does <!-- Not Throw a Syntax Error?

Tags: javascript, syntax, standards, grammar

I noticed in some legacy code the following pattern:

```
<script>
    <!--
    // code
    // -->
</script>
```

After some research, this appears to be a *very* old technique for hiding the contents of script elements from the DOM when the browser did not support the `<script>` element. More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808816/are-html-comments-inside-script-tags-a-best-practice).

My concern is this: **why does `<!--` not throw a Syntax Error?** I've found on [whatwg.org's website](https://javascript.spec.whatwg.org/#comment-syntax) that `<!--` should be functionally equivalent to `//`, and it links off to a snippet from the [ECMAScript grammar about comments](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-comments). The problem is, `<!--` isn't defined by that grammar at all.

So this seems like undefined behavior that happens to be implemented by all major browsers. Is there a specification that allows for this, or is this a backwards-compatibility hack that people are bringing forward?

Comment: It's not part of JS, it's part of html.

Comment: Does it work on external JS files or just inside HTML files?

Comment: It works in external script files as well. And @nnnnnn, why is the HTML parser interpreting my JavaScript? Seems fishy.

Comment: It works in Node's REPL, for example. So I doubt it's only matter of HTML.

Comment: Interesting, it seems to be silently ignored in the middle of code, too.  For example: http://jsfiddle.net/4cegngew/  If I put some other syntax error in between any two lines I see that other error reported in the console, but I don't see the "comment" line reported at all.

Comment: There's some pretty good related info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808816/are-html-comments-inside-script-tags-a-best-practice

Comment: Raynjamin - I would say that the HTML parser isn't interpreting your JS, but it has to figure out which part of the file actually is JS to pass to the JS engine, so... (Unfortunately, of course, that doesn't explain why it works in external script files.)

Comment: @nnnnnn In case of V8 (at least), it's a matter of how JS engine parse the JS code ([sort-of-proof](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/c395b4c7aa67e0ae308650e5ebcfd294bfb3d6a0/src/scanner.cc#L396)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Officially: Because there's [specific handling for it](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements) in the HTML spec. E.g., it's a "by fait" thing. It's not a JavaScript thing, you won't find it in the JavaScript grammar.

Unofficially, it would appear that at least some JavaScript engines handle it intrinsically, sometimes in ways that make what I believe is valid JavaScript invalid. For instance, on V8 in a browser, this fails:

```js
eval("var a = 1; var n = 3; console.log(a<!--n);")
```

...with `Unexpected end of input`. I'm pretty sure it **shouldn't**, but I'm not a parsing lawyer. I'd expect it to log `false` to the console, like this does:

```js
eval("var a = 1; var n = 3; console.log(a<! --n);")
// Note the space -------------------------^
```

Side note: Meteor's [jsparser](http://jsparse.meteor.com/) agrees with me, copy and paste just the bit inside the double quotes into it.

Note that the characters `<!` do not appear in [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1), nor does there appear to be anything near any of the 70 occurrences of the word "comment" in there, nor is it anywhere in the [comment grammar](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.4), so it wouldn't seem to be an explicit in-spec exception. It's just something at least some JavaScript engines do to avoid getting messed up by people doing silly things. No great surprise. :-)

Comment: Then why it's ok to go in the browser's console? In Node.js REPL?

Comment: I can put it anywhere-- inline script elements, external JS references, console.. all works just fine.

Comment: @raina77ow Personally I'd see it as a case of "well this is obviously not JS syntax so I can just safely assume what you meant to say and continue along happily".

Comment: @raynjamin: Officially, as far as I know, it's just a browser thing. But it doesn't surprise me **at all** to hear that JavaScript engines allow for it at the beginning of something they parse. Pragmatism.

Comment: What about `eval('3 + 3<!--');` then? )

Comment: @raina77ow: If that works, I'm impressed. But it's outside spec, just the JavaScript engine folks being pragmatic. Kinda makes me want to play with things like `if (a<!--n)` but I'm sure it's contextually-aware.

Comment: It works both in Chrome's console and in node.js REPL machine. ) Have no means to try other browserless JS implementations, but won't be surprised if they follow the same approach. Yet the OP is right, it seems to be missing from ES (5, at least).

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol var x = ({a:function(c){this.b.push(c);return c?this.a(--c):this.b;},b:[]}.a(~+!"">>>+!""));

With JS, I always pause before thinking "This is obviously not valid Syntax."

Comment: Yes, `<!-` will throw an error. And I fail to see any clear difference in 'obviousity' for these two. )

Comment: @raina77ow: Oh wow, `eval("var a = 1; var n = 3; console.log(a<!--n);")` fails with `Unexpected end of input` on V8. Yikes.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yet this jewel - `eval('if(2<!--3){4}else{5}\n){6}');` - gives 6, as expected - if `<!--` is treated equivalent to `//`, that is. ) But remove `{6}`, and it'll fail with an error.

Comment: Actually TJ I would expect your latest code snippets to throw the exceptions you're seeing. If you replace that with // you get the same exception.

Comment: @raynjamin Yes, but that - `a<!--n` - IS a valid expression on its own - in the same way as `< !--n` is. Now, compare two expressions: `3 < !--n` and `3 <!--n`; why on Earth they should be treated differently? )

Comment: @raina77ow Yeah because that's functionally equivalent to a//n

Comment: @raynjamin: Right, but `<!--` is not a [JavaScript comment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.4).

Comment: Ugh. And I thought dependency on `</scr/ipt` was bad enough. )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Haha T.J., thus my question! It's not in a grammar but  I have other sources that say it is functionally equivalent. See the whatwg.org link

Comment: @raina77ow They should be treated differently because the behavior we're experiencing is related to <!-- being treated EXACTLY like //. If you interrupt it with spaces, the JS errors out.

Comment: @raynjamin: The WHAT-WG do not control the actual specifications, not for HTML (yet), and not for JavaScript. I wouldn't be surprised if the WHAT-WG ends up directly controlling HTML at some point (the W3C certainly dropped that ball and stomped on it), but I very much doubt you'll see them controlling the specification for JavaScript this decade at the very least, ECMA's TC-39 committee is active and industry is well-represented. So in that link some group in the WHAT-WG is documenting what they, as an industry body, want to document and consider best practice. Not what the spec says.

Comment: And here's some [source code food for thought](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/c395b4c7aa67e0ae308650e5ebcfd294bfb3d6a0/src/scanner.cc#L396).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [copied to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63136/discussion-on-answer-by-t-j-crowder-why-does-not-throw-a-syntax-error").

Comment: That's why the thread was copied, not moved T.J. - the bulk of this thread does relate to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is defined by the [**W3's docs**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#idx-user_agent) for the user agents:

> The JavaScript engine allows the string `"<!--"` to occur at the start of a SCRIPT element, and ignores further characters until the end of the line.

So browsers follow these standards