# Javascript email onclick validation not working

Tags: javascript, html, web, web-deployment

For some reason, the javascript function "validateEmail" isn't working. Could someone please let me know what I did wrong? I wanted to use an onblur event within the email section of the form, but that doesn't seem to be working. I have tried other codes to validate the email but none worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Truth or Dare </title>
<script type="text/javascript">   
<!--
function validateEmail() {

var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
if( email="null" || email="")
{
window.alert("Please input a valid email address");
}
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<tr>
<form>
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"  maxlength="30" /> <br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"  maxlength="30"/> <br>
Email: <input type="text" id="email" /> <br>
Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/>
Female <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/> <br>
Date to be performed:<input type="date" name="date"/><br>
Victim:  <input type="text" name="victim"  maxlength="30" />
<input type="submit" onclick="validateEmail();" />
</form>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you mean to comment out the function?

Comment: @APAD1 My lecturer told me it was the standard way of writing the Javascript and we are required to do it that way.

Comment: You should tell your lecturer that it's no longer 1995 ;) Definitely [not a good practice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/808850/2827407) these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
email == null || email == ""
```

Answer (score 1):

`if( email="null" || email="")` is missing triple equals. Also you should be checking for `null`, not `"null"`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Truth or Dare </title>
<script type="text/javascript">   
<!--
function validateEmail() {

var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
if( email===null || email==="")
{
window.alert("Please input a valid email address");
}
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<tr>
<form>
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"  maxlength="30" /> <br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"  maxlength="30"/> <br>
Email: <input type="text" id="email" /> <br>
Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/>
Female <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/> <br>
Date to be performed:<input type="date" name="date"/><br>
Victim:  <input type="text" name="victim"  maxlength="30" />
<input type="submit" onclick="validateEmail();" />
</form>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this:

```
if (email == null || email == "")
```

You left out the double equals `==`, which is the equality operator for comparisons.

Also, when using the value `null`, you don't need to enclose it in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

"=" to assign value,
"==" to check value

```
if (email == "null" || email == "") {
    window.alert("Please input a valid email address");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You are missing one = in the comparison, try this:

```
if( email== "null" || email== "")
```

Otherwise you are assigning instead of comparing

Comment: You don't surround null with quotes, if you are wondering why you are being downvoted.