# javascript generate random number

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<p>Click the button to display a random number between 1 and 10.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I created a html file on dreamweaver, but it said that I have error and I can't find the error, help!!!

Comment: What is it giving you as the error? The code works just fine.

Comment: Your code is flawless.. no error. If there is, can you post the error?

Comment: Doesn't the Javascript debugger tell you which line the error is on?

Comment: dreamweaver display a message that there is a syntax error on line 1.

Comment: what is `it` that tells you such things? I think `it` is making it up ...works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/y9buepaL/

Comment: could it be expecting a head?

Comment: Use `sublime` instead.. :)

Comment: Would my dreamweaver have some problem?

Comment: @Dyrandz Closest thing he will probably get to an answer.

Comment: @user3881958 give it head and see it it cooperates then...

Comment: are you using a fairly old version of dream weaver?

Comment: @user3881958 Good for you.. that should also work on dreamweaver but maybe there's something the dreamweaver required that you've missed..  but `sublime` also is great.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

By using the W3C Validator at http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input
I was able to see the validation error.

Copied from W3C.org:

```
 Line 4, Column 6: Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.
```

These errors will not affect the literal usability of your application but it is always a good idea to do your best to not have any validation errors in your HTML. I am not an HTML validation expert but if you do not have valid HTML, some browsers may not act as you designed.

I suggest you use the W3C.org validator often to verify your code.

Comment: I knew it.... Cool tool, I didn't know it existed. Upvote.

Answer (score 0):

in some old ver. IE, code need to like this:

```
<script><!--
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
//--></script>
```

Comment: This is not necessary, and hasn't been for about a decade. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808816/are-html-comments-inside-script-tags-a-best-practice.