# Comment styles in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple scripts I've inherited to say the least. These scripts work flawlessly in Chrome and FireFox but IE not so much

Today I noticed something while trying to figure it out. I noticed that at the top of the scripts are some comments but they look like

```
<!-- 
/*
*
* The comment
*
*/
-->
```

Is the HTML style comments potentially breaking the scripts in IE? the `<!-- -->` part

Comment: If that's in a  `<Script>` block, I would venture to say yes (given it's not valid javascript). Though, IMHO, it _should_ break. If FF/Chrome are suppressing it, they're just lending pages to continue to be effed up.

Comment: Suggest reading this thread... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808816/are-html-comments-inside-script-tags-a-best-practice

Comment: Its within a JS file specifically well a few of them rather. Who ever designed our Grunt flow, has these injected in like this. Which didn't seem right to me.. but it caught my eye since I know IE can be real particular about things, where as FF and Chrome sometimes look past it so to speak

Comment: I just couldn't find reference saying that the combination in the way presented was in so many words, legal..

Comment: it's not valid to use xml comments in js files, but some vendors might try to fix it for you automatically.

Comment: Just how old are these scripts? Are they etched in stone perhaps?

Comment: You would think they should be haha.. but no.. well, no actually maybe some of them are..

Answer (score 0):

The syntax would need to change to

```
<!-- 
/*
*
* The comment
*
*/ 

//-->
```

< !--  is a valid js comment, but --> is not

Comment: Thats pretty much what I thought, but I couldn't find anything saying yes/no to 100% either way if it was allowable. `//-->` I knew about but yea, overall I believe this solidifies my concern about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `<!-- -->` comments inside javascript and stick with `/* */`.