# Chrome - Javascript engine parsing behavior

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, comments, javascript-engine

HTML comments are allowed in Javascript, for older browsers which are not aware of `<script>` tags.

Ref: [Are HTML comments inside script tags a best practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808816/are-html-comments-inside-script-tags-a-best-practice)

So, the JS parser allows `<!--` at the start of script, which will be ignored for parsing. And, `-->` should be prefixed with `//` so that JS engine ignores them too.

Ref W3C: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.3.2

While playing with this, I saw this weird behaviour.

```
<script>
    <!--
    alert(1);
    -->
</script>
```

Here, note that `-->` isn't prefixed by `//`, which should throw an error by Chrome JS engine. But, Chrome JS engine consider them to be comments, and ignore parsing. Why? (Q1)

And, another behaviour:

```
<script>
    alert(1);
    -->''>{][}
</script>
```

This snippet will execute alert. Here, note the place of `-->`. This specific sequence of characters makes the parser `ignore` all other incorrect values following it. 
What I mean is, in place of `-->`, use any other character/sequence, it will throw error.

So, what's happening here? How `-->` makes this snippet valid? (Q2)

Note: `-->` sequence should be prefixed with a new line. That is,

```
<script>
    <!--
    alert(1); -->''>{][}
</script>
```

will throw an error. Again, why? (Q3)

Answer (score -1):

Well! All the three code snippets that you have provided gives me error saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" on Chrome.

Comment: Ignore `<script>` and `</script>` tags if you paste the code in console.