# How to remove HTML from scripts?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have a script with both HTML and javascript inside:

```
<script>
  <br>
  window.onload = myFunction;
  <br>
  function myFunction() {
    // Do something
  }
  <br>
</script>
```

Obviously, the HTML dont work, but can I remove the HTML tags in scripts somehow? With the javascript code still working. (and not by just going into the code and removing the HTML myself). Is there a way to make the HTML go away or be invisible to the script?

(I've tried just commenting it out with the "< ! - -" and "- - >" but it doesn't work)

Edit: the reason I'm wondering is because I have a weird coding teacher... and he told me you could do stuff like that but I can't get it to work. So I just want to know if it's actually possible.

Comment: So my guess is that you have a script that doesn't work either. This is neither valid JS or valid HTML, this is a mess.

Comment: to comment stuff out in js you use `//`, `<!-- -->` is for html

Comment: You should do whatever it takes to... avoid everything thats happening here.

Comment: The commenting doesn't work because those are HTML comments not JavaScript comments and you're in a `script` tag. Semantically speaking, this is wrong on many levels. What would be the reason for not wanting to edit the original source and instead provide a hack to make this work?...

Comment: In JS, you can comment out a line using `//` and multiple lines using `/* */`.

Comment: HTML comments _do_ work in Javascript. It isn't a great solution, but saying they are not valid is incorrect. They are valid for legacy reasons and do not throw errors..

Comment: @rlemon good point, see here for more information - https://stackoverflow.com/q/808816/864233 - and the W3C Spec - https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.3.2

Comment: Are you asking if you can do this without actually editing the script, but make it happen automatically when you load the page?

Comment: Well, thank you all for explaining. I finally understand now... this website is alot more helpful than my teacher. Do I do anything with this post now that I've gotten my answer? Delete it? Or just leave it like this?

Comment: If the question has become moot, you can delete it. Or if you think you've figured out the solution from the comments, you can post an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting the code using javascript comment tags /*

```
<script>
/*  
 <br>
  window.onload = myFunction;
 <br> 
*/
  function myFunction() {
    // Do something
  }
  <br>
</script>
```