# Why are javascripts sometimes surrounded by these tags?

Tags: javascript

Why are some JavaScripts encapsulated within these tags:

```
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--

some js here

//--><!]]>
```

Comment: you only use them in a html file. All modern browser don't need it anymore, but the w3c validator does if you use certain characters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<![CDATA[//>` is to prevent XML parsers from choking on the script.

`<!-- ... -->` is not required unless you're using Netscape 1.0.

See: [Does it still make sense to use HTML comments on blocks of JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204813/does-it-still-make-sense-to-use-html-comments-on-blocks-of-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

It makes it [valid](http://javascript.about.com/library/blxhtml.htm) [XHTML](http://www.codehouse.com/javascript/tips/xhtml/).

Answer (score 2):

They were used for old browsers which didn't understand the `<script>` tag.  That way if a browser didn't properly read the JavaScript, it would just render it as a comment and not show up on the page.

It also allows JavaScript code to be inside valid XHTML pages without having to escape characters which aren't valid in XML.

Comment: I was trying to think about that.  Not that I know of, but I suppose you could still run into someone who uses it....not that it would (most likely) render any modern page today though.

Comment: Except for any modern browser in XHTML mode. It's an alternative to escaping all `<`s and `&`s in your `<script>` tag. It also applies to RSS feeds and the like.

Comment: @Williham Totland true enough, I have updated the answer to add that in.