# Simple JavaScript formatting

Tags: javascript, squarespace

Sorry to be such a noob, but I've looked for this answer and can't find anything relevant.

Im trying to add some [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)code to a squarespace website. The code is to display a random image.

I have to format the code and insert links to where my images are hosted but I'm not sure what to format

This is the bare code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  <!--

  /*
  Random Image Script- By JavaScript Kit (http://www.javascriptkit.com) 
  Over 400+ free JavaScripts here!
  Keep this notice intact please
  */

  function random_imglink() {
    var myimages = new Array()
    //specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
    myimages[1] = "image1.gif"
    myimages[2] = "image2.gif"
    myimages[3] = "image3.gif"
    myimages[4] = "image4.gif"
    myimages[5] = "image5.gif"
    myimages[6] = "image6.gif"

    var ry = Math.floor(Math.random() * myimages.length)
    if (ry == 0)
      ry = 1
    document.write('<img src="' + myimages[ry] + '" border=0>')
  }
  random_imglink()
  //-->
</script>

<p align="center">This free script provided by<br />
  <a href="http://javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a>
</p>
```

And this is the links I've added? have i edited it correctly?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  <!--

  /*
  Random Image Script- By JavaScript Kit (http://www.javascriptkit.com) 
  Over 400+ free JavaScripts here!
  Keep this notice intact please
  */

  function random_imglink() {
    var symimages = new Array()
    //specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
    symimages[1] = "1.jpg"
    symimages[2] = "2.jpg"
    symimages[3] = "3.jpg"
    symimages[4] = "4.jpg"
    symimages[5] = "5.jpg"


    var ry = Math.floor(Math.random() * symimages.length)
    if (ry == 0)
      ry = 1
     document.write('<img src="http://www.mattselley.com/symimages'+symimages[ry]+'" border=0>')
}
    random_imglink()
    //-->
</script>

<p align="center">This free script provided by<br />
  <a href="http://javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a>
</p>
```

When I add that code to the squarespace site, in code injection, it doest work, so I'm missing something here, and i think i haven't got the links correct - this is supposed to be a cut and paste code, so I'm doing something wrong.

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it shows any error or just the images are not loading there?

Comment: Where is your images which you want to be loaded there?

Comment: this site is for my partner and the images are hosted on the server to my own website.

Comment: doesn't show any errors - just not working at all.

Comment: you can see in the example code above that the 'img src' link is greyed out - so i presume its something to do with this?

Comment: Hmm, your script is enclosed in an HTML comment.  That's a pretty obsolete practice. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204813/does-it-still-make-sense-to-use-html-comments-on-blocks-of-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<scripe language="JavaScript">
var imgs = ['http://lorempizza.com/380/240', 
            'http://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000', 
            'http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/', 
            'http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/sports/'];
var container = document.getElementById('imageContainer');
var ry = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length)
if (ry == 0)
  ry = 1
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = imgs[ry]; // img[i] refers to the current URL.
container.appendChild(img);
</script>


<div id="imageContainer">  </div>
```

This is what you want. Just replace my that urls with yours.

OR if you want to go with your approach..make correction as ..

```
document.write('<img src="http://www.mattselley.com/symimages/'+symimages[ry]+'" border=0>')
```

add / at then end of src.

Dont forget to Tick and Upvote ;)